# Rails: Acts as votable gem - allow unlimited votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) running. But it only allows 1 vote per user. As described in [here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#registered-votes) you can allow multiple votes per user onto one record.

That's what I got in my controller:

```
def vote
  @feature_request.vote_by voter: @user, :duplicate => true
  redirect_to :back
end
```

my view:

```
 <%= link_to like_feature_request_path(feature_request), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  Upvote
  <%= feature_request.get_upvotes.size %>
 <% end %>
```

my routes:

```
resources :feature_requests do
 member do
  put "like", to: "feature_requests#vote"
 end
end
```

my model:

```
class FeatureRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
In my controller:

```
@feature_request.vote_by voter: current_user, :duplicate => true
```

I changed `@user` to `current_user`.